# Sending a message from a node to its neighbour

Tags: c++, grid, omnet++, sensors

I am trying to create a grid network and send messages. 
My Node is as follows:

```
simple Node
{
    parameters:
        @display("i=misc/node");
        gates:
        inout up;
        inout left;
        inout down;
        inout right;
}
```

And i am sending a msg as follows:

```
if(this->gate("right$o")->isConnected())
        {
            send(msg,"right$o",k);
        }
```

It doesn't give any build errors but gives an error in simulation. What am i doing wrong? The error is as below:

```
send()/sendDelayed(): Scalar gate 'right$o' referenced with index -- in module (Node) GridNetwork.sensor[0] (id=2), at t=0s, event #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Your example `Node` has a `inout right` gate, which is a scalar `inout` gate rather than a vector. This means that there's only one, and it has two gates: `right$i` and `right$o`, as you're trying to use in your example.

You must thus replace `inout right` with `inout right[]`, as well as create connections from it to another gate. See [the OMNeT++ documentation on gates](https://doc.omnetpp.org/omnetpp/manual/#sec:ned-lang:gates).